# Google Analytics events and multiple categories

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a single website deployed in multiple configurations. Simplified example:

- Manufacturer **A** + Vendor **L** + Product **X** + **Staging** mode
- Manufacturer **A** + Vendor **L** + Product **X** + **Production** mode
- Manufacturer **B** + Vendor **M** + Product **Y** + **Production** mode
- Manufacturer **B** + Vendor **M** + Product **Z** + **Production** mode
- Manufacturer **B** + Vendor **N** + Product **Z** + **Production** mode

And we want to track all of them within a single Google Analytics property. Currently we track just various click events (e.g. "add to cart button clicked" or "order button clicked"), using Google Tag Manager, and we GTM variables defined for all configuration options (which are pretty much independent of each other).

How do we go about categorizing all that? We don't want to concatenate all variables into a single category, since we might want to explore a slice of our events, e.g. by a single manufacturer or just production mode, or a combination of variables, like "manufacturer B + vendor N". Content Grouping?

Just in case, we do need to track staging too, and we can't rely on the domains/URLs, just the variables extracted from the page using GTM.

Comment: For staging vs production you should use different Google Analytics property IDs.   Track your staging servers separately so  that none of their data gets mixed in with the live data.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yep, thanks, that's what we went with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Dimensions turned out to be the way to go. Once setup (each configuration variable getting its own dimension), we were able to use them for view filtering / custom report generation / etc. Make sure to give it a day or so before attempting to use the dimensions, since it appears that Google takes some time to process them.